# System (often) freezes after hibernation

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, lenovo, hibernate, resume

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 with Linux 5.11 on Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 15ARH05.

Hibernation mostly works without problems, but sometimes the system freezes after resume. I can see the mouse pointer, but I can't move it. Switching TTYs doesn't work too.

Here's a kernel log I was able to get:

```
<3>[48338.332848] swap_info_get: Bad swap offset entry 3ff7fffffffff
<3>[48338.332854] swap_info_get: Bad swap offset entry 3ffeb0cfeffff
<1>[48338.599999] BUG: Bad page map in process ksysguard  pte:40002600000001 pmd:117dba067
<1>[48338.600011] addr:00007fda48a08000 vm_flags:08000075 anon_vma:0000000000000000 mapping:ffff9cba1c90f1b8 index:1b
<1>[48338.600018] file:libpcre.so.3.13.3 fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
<4>[48338.600034] CPU: 6 PID: 9468 Comm: ksysguard Tainted: P    B      OE     5.11.11-anbox #2
<4>[48338.600039] Hardware name: LENOVO 82EY/LNVNB161216, BIOS FCCN13WW 06/29/2020
<4>[48338.600041] Call Trace:
<4>[48338.600047]  dump_stack+0x74/0x92
<4>[48338.600054]  print_bad_pte.cold+0x6a/0xca
<4>[48338.600059]  ? avc_has_perm+0xca/0x1f0
<4>[48338.600064]  vm_normal_page+0xc5/0xd0
<4>[48338.600069]  smaps_pte_range+0x4a9/0x5b0
<4>[48338.600074]  __walk_page_range+0x5f5/0xc30
<4>[48338.600081]  walk_page_vma+0x85/0xa0
<4>[48338.600086]  smap_gather_stats.part.0+0x9d/0xc0
<4>[48338.600091]  show_smaps_rollup+0x124/0x350
<4>[48338.600097]  seq_read_iter+0x1c5/0x4c0
<4>[48338.600102]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
<4>[48338.600108]  seq_read+0xfd/0x150
<4>[48338.600112]  vfs_read+0xb5/0x1b0
<4>[48338.600118]  ksys_read+0x67/0xe0
<4>[48338.600124]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
<4>[48338.600129]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
<4>[48338.600134]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
<4>[48338.600139] RIP: 0033:0x7f370fdd917c
<4>[48338.600144] Code: ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24 10 89 7c 24 08 e8 f9 65 f8 ff 48 8b 54 24 18 48 8b 74 24 10 41 89 c0 8b 7c 24 08 31 c0 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 30 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 2f 66 f8 ff 48
<4>[48338.600148] RSP: 002b:00007fff5f0d6750 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
Oops#1 Part15
<4>[48338.332615] CPU: 10 PID: 9468 Comm: ksysguard Tainted: P    B      OE     5.11.11-anbox #2
<4>[48338.332624] Hardware name: LENOVO 82EY/LNVNB161216, BIOS FCCN13WW 06/29/2020
<4>[48338.332627] Call Trace:
<4>[48338.332634]  dump_stack+0x74/0x92
<4>[48338.332643]  print_bad_pte.cold+0x6a/0xca
<4>[48338.332648]  ? avc_has_perm+0xca/0x1f0
<4>[48338.332655]  vm_normal_page+0xc5/0xd0
<4>[48338.332659]  smaps_pte_range+0x4a9/0x5b0
<4>[48338.332664]  __walk_page_range+0x5f5/0xc30
<4>[48338.332671]  walk_page_vma+0x85/0xa0
<4>[48338.332677]  smap_gather_stats.part.0+0x9d/0xc0
<4>[48338.332681]  show_smaps_rollup+0x124/0x350
<4>[48338.332687]  seq_read_iter+0x1c5/0x4c0
<4>[48338.332692]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
<4>[48338.332698]  seq_read+0xfd/0x150
<4>[48338.332703]  vfs_read+0xb5/0x1b0
<4>[48338.332709]  ksys_read+0x67/0xe0
<4>[48338.332714]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
<4>[48338.332720]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
<4>[48338.332725]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
<4>[48338.332730] RIP: 0033:0x7f370fdd917c
<4>[48338.332735] Code: ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24 10 89 7c 24 08 e8 f9 65 f8 ff 48 8b 54 24 18 48 8b 74 24 10 41 89 c0 8b 7c 24 08 31 c0 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 30 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 2f 66 f8 ff 48
<4>[48338.332740] RSP: 002b:00007fff5f0d5750 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
<4>[48338.332743] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f36f400d6d0 RCX: 00007f370fdd917c
<4>[48338.332743] RDX: 0000000000004000 RSI: 000055e949c07618 RDI: 0000000000000016
<4>[48338.332743] RBP: 0000000000004000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f370e4d9698
<4>[48338.332743] R10: 0000000000004000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
<4>[48338.332743] R13: 0000000000004000 R14: 0000000000000016 R15: 000055e949c07618
Oops#1 Part4
<6>[45091.932552] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
<6>[45091.958198] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
<6>[45091.972534] [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010014
<6>[45092.129949] [drm] Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
<6>[45092.158308] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
<6>[45092.158377] [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
<6>[45092.158679] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158685] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158688] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158691] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158693] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158695] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158698] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158700] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158702] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158705] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
<6>[45092.158708] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
<6>[45092.158711] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
<6>[45092.158713] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
<6>[45092.158715] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
<6>[45092.158718] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
```

I tried to search for this swap issue, but all I was able to get was that the RAM is corrupt. It's a new laptop, and this issue has been happening since I bought it, so it's unlikely.

Note that this laptop had problems with Linux before, like no brightness and touchpad not working. Linux 5.8 added support for this new AMD CPU (AMD Ryzen 5 4600H) and Linux 5.11 fixed the touchpad. Linux 5.12 and above break the touchpad again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is happening only when hybrid graphics (NVIDIA proprietary driver) is enabled. If I switch to the integrated GPU using `sudo prime-select intel`, resume works fine.